# Sudden Loss of Internet Access – Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet, internet-connection

I have spent much of the day reviewing similar issues reported here but alas I have not been able to identify any which correspond with the unique aspects in this case.

The Issue:

Following the application of Windows Update KB4486553 (which may or may not be implicated) and the subsequent re-boot, the PC lost all internet connectivity through both Ethernet connections and the USB Wi-Fi Connection. All other devices on the network (including another similarly updated X99 Windows 10 PC) are unaffected.

Unusually, and perhaps evident only because the PC is an old X58 (Asus P6T7 board) and so boots slowly, on any re-boot the internet is initially connected (as evidenced by Google page, Outlook 2016, TeamViewer connection, WhatsApp access, OneDrive, Dropbox, etc.). However, within a couple of minutes (during the start-up sequencing), all connection is lost. 
However, the network settings "status" continues to report "You're connected to the Internet" (though clearly not) and no warning triangles are displayed either on the taskbar (or elsewhere).

Troubleshooting Steps (as attempted thus far as I am able to recall):

- Uninstall the Windows Update which preceded the problem
- Re-Start PC (Numerous Times)
- Re-Start/Re-Boot Router (Multiple Times)
- Swap both Ethernet Leads (with known good)
- Wi-Fi Network Report (graph shows connect/disconnects)
- Ping (Gateway IP) – Always successful
- Ping (Internet) – Always fails (to be fair, by the time I am able to Ping this is always after the connection has dropped)
- Run Network Troubleshooter (Windows could not automatically detect this network's proxy settings)
- Reset the TCP/IP Stack (`netsh winsock reset`/`netsh int ip reset`)
- Release/Renew IP Address (`ipconfig /renew & ipconfig /renew`)
- Flush and reset the DNS client resolver cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`)
- Uninstalled, replaced and subsequently (as a further step) updated Network Adapter Drivers to latest released
- Disabled (for testing) Antivirus & Firewall software
- Attempted a System Restore to three separate recent restore point (all fail to complete citing anti-virus despite this being disabled prior to restore attempts)
- From within Windows 10 settings perform Network reset
- Re-boot to Safe Mode with Networking also selective startup (`msconfig`) for diagnostic purposes
- Compare network settings against working Windows 10 machine for anomalies
- Review of Event Viewer logs (Applications & Services logs)
- Microsoft/Windows/Universal Telemetry Client

```
    Event 55 Reports: "Is the Internet available:true"
     Error 29 Reports: "Connection state - Some connections have failed since the previous period."
```

Not attempted so far (due to potential loss of wide ranging complex menu tweaks applied to facilitate ease of use)

- In place system repair install

The situation as described above continues to occur in all scenarios despite applying the above troubleshooting steps, often multiple times and in various combinations.

Accordingly I would welcome any ideas as to what else I can try and how this might be resolved.

```
PC Pilot

Route Print Output (at initial start up – connected)

===========================================================================
Interface List
  6...20 cf 30 e4 1d 84 ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
 21...20 cf 30 e4 1e 7f ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
 12...0a 00 27 00 00 0c ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 20...00 ff a2 97 37 5b ......Npcap Loopback Adapter
 27...b2 6e bf a9 4d 25 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
 13...b0 6e bf a9 4d 25 ......ASUS USB-AC68 USB Wireless adapter
 19...00 ff 9d ee fa 7f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 11...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 26...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1    192.168.50.21     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1    192.168.50.20     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1   192.168.50.136     30
       10.10.10.8  255.255.255.252         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
       10.10.10.9  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
      10.10.10.11  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
   169.254.154.40  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
     192.168.35.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.35.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
   192.168.35.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
    192.168.50.20  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
    192.168.50.21  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
   192.168.50.136  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
    192.168.106.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
    192.168.106.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
  192.168.106.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  6    281 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
 21    281 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
 13    286 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942:0:2947:65cd:7044:a9e1/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942:0:75ad:a534:4f40:4541/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942:0:9127:d446:6938:4bf5/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942:0:a567:2726:4944:4447/128
                                    On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942:0:cd3d:e955:bc68:b9c5/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942:0:f4c5:2d69:c1b:1601/128
                                    On-link
 26    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    291 fe80::14b:3533:f9b:611f/128
                                    On-link
 13    286 fe80::2947:65cd:7044:a9e1/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::383c:d35f:ddc0:9a28/128
                                    On-link
 11    291 fe80::61c1:6a17:dd7e:ea90/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 fe80::75ad:a534:4f40:4541/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 fe80::a567:2726:4944:4447/128
                                    On-link
 26    291 fe80::f9b6:5a73:ff7b:4300/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 26    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 19    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None


Route Print Output (at initial start up + 1 minute – disconnected)

===========================================================================
Interface List
  6...20 cf 30 e4 1d 84 ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller
 21...20 cf 30 e4 1e 7f ......Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
 12...0a 00 27 00 00 0c ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 20...00 ff a2 97 37 5b ......Npcap Loopback Adapter
 27...b2 6e bf a9 4d 25 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #5
 13...b0 6e bf a9 4d 25 ......ASUS USB-AC68 USB Wireless adapter
 19...00 ff 9d ee fa 7f ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 11...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 26...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1    192.168.50.21     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1    192.168.50.20     26
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1   192.168.50.136     30
       10.10.10.8  255.255.255.252         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
       10.10.10.9  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
      10.10.10.11  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
   169.254.154.40  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
     192.168.35.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.35.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
   192.168.35.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
    192.168.50.20  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
    192.168.50.21  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
   192.168.50.136  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
    192.168.106.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
    192.168.106.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
  192.168.106.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.106.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.154.40    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.9    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.21    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.20    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.50.136    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.50.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  6    281 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
 21    281 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
 13    286 ::/0                     fe80::e9d:92ff:fe01:8588
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942::/64       On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942:0:2947:65cd:7044:a9e1/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942:0:75ad:a534:4f40:4541/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942:0:9127:d446:6938:4bf5/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 2001:470:1942:0:a567:2726:4944:4447/128
                                    On-link
 13    286 2001:470:1942:0:cd3d:e955:bc68:b9c5/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 2001:470:1942:0:f4c5:2d69:c1b:1601/128
                                    On-link
 26    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  6    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    291 fe80::14b:3533:f9b:611f/128
                                    On-link
 13    286 fe80::2947:65cd:7044:a9e1/128
                                    On-link
 12    281 fe80::383c:d35f:ddc0:9a28/128
                                    On-link
 11    291 fe80::61c1:6a17:dd7e:ea90/128
                                    On-link
  6    281 fe80::75ad:a534:4f40:4541/128
                                    On-link
 21    281 fe80::a567:2726:4944:4447/128
                                    On-link
 26    291 fe80::f9b6:5a73:ff7b:4300/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 26    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 19    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  6    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: I would try a System Restore point date before the KB was installed that caused the trouble.

Comment: Can you add the output of `route print` to your question? Open command prompt and type `route print`.

Comment: Hi to MOAB & Andy 

Many thanks for your contributions, your assistance is greatly appreciated :)

MOAB, I guess you missed it in my somewhat comprehensive summary but I had attempted to Restore only to find that Windows 10 will not complete citing Anti Virus conflict (NB. AV and firewall were disabled temporarily before attemting these "restores").

Andy, as requested please find attached below the output from "Route Print" the first taken during the startup sequence whilst (apparently) the internet connection was established and the 2nd 1 min later after the internet connection fails.

Comment: During further testing I became aware of further peculiar anomaly. During the shut down sequence on the X58 machine, the Team Viewer App on the X99 Machine reports that the X58 machine has signed in (i.e.. indicates that the internet connection has become active), naturally this is very brief as the X58 then restarts with the results reported in my original post.

Comment: Incidentally, I also omitted to advise that both ethernet adapters are configured to Static IP addresses (and were before the issue) by command line as follows (NB: Ethernet 2 is similarly configured as 192.168.50.21):

netsh interface ip set address name="Realtek RTL8111C PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Adapter - Ethernet 1" static 192.168.50.20 255.255.255.0 192.168.50.1

netsh interface ip set dns name="Realtek RTL8111C PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Adapter - Ethernet 1" static  8.8.8.8

netsh interface ip add dns name="Realtek RTL8111C PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Adapter - Ethernet 1" 8.8.4.4 index=2

Comment: Please [do not edit your original question to include an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/271445). Instead, post an answer on your question.

Answer (score -2):

A quick update with the solution in the hope it helps anybody else struggling with the same issue. Finally tracked down the cause.

Despite the numerous troubleshooting steps over 10 days described in the Q, including from "safe mode" and with start-up items supposedly disabled bizarrely the culprit turned out to be the IPVanish VPN Windows app (which I can only surmise had experienced some form of corruption during the Windows Update restart) and a check box setting called "kill switch" which was found mysteriously enabled deep within the app.

IPVanish has always been configured to start with "Windows" but in a VPN disconnected state. It would seem that IPVanish is deeply embedded in the start-up sequence. The fact it was set to start disconnected (for reasons of issues reaching the email servers whilst connected to the VPN when using Outlook, which itself is set to auto-start with Windows 10 and so to collect my email in the background) triggered the protection offered by the (now enabled) kill switch.

IPVanish provides the following helpful summary of "Kill Switch":

What is a Kill Switch? A kill switch shuts down all Internet traffic if/when your current VPN connection stops working. This is a great feature to enable if you want to maximize your privacy and anonymity because having a kill switch kills your internet if you are not being protected by the VPN. This means your privacy will still be safe and secure even if connection to our VPN is lost.

IPVanish goes on to provide the following interesting comment:

If you are having any trouble connecting to the Internet, please double-check to make sure that the Kill Switch has not been enabled.

Comment: Answers don't go in questions, and it's perfectly OK for askers to answer their own question. So take all the information you added to the question earlier and EDIT this answer and paste it here and everything will be just fine.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of doing what @music2myear suggested, though I had to grab it from the revision history. Further edits welcome, especially from OP!

Comment: Apologies to all for the poor layout of my answer and thanks to bertieb for making the appropriate corrections on my behalf, very much appreciated!